# Trying to rig the character in pose mode

Tags: rigging, rigify, pose-mode

Hello I'm following this tutorial to rig my dog but i can't make the dog move. And i'm really new to blender.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LM50gJJOrQ

I'm already in the part **05:18** which i should able to move it

This is the screenshot from the tutorial

[image]

[image]

And this is the screenshot from my blender

[image]

We can see that I'm not following the tutorials.

My questions are:

1. How do i make the view as in the tutorial
2. How can i move the rig? The cursor of mine is the usual cursor. Like the one using when browsing the internet. But in the tutorial his cursor is something like a cursair. So how can make it like that so i can move the rig?

This is my blender file https://drive.google.com/file/d/13Sls8MNf7tyigEU3WZ_sNSeZGZsc9PkX/view?usp=sharing. Thank you

Comment: Hello, your question is not clear, what are you referring to in question 1? If you are talking about the wireframe display you need to go in the Properties panel > Object > Viewport Display > enable Wireframe option. For your question 2, to move the rig you need to switch to Pose mode: select the armature then ctrl tab I suppose, or header bar and on the left, click on the dropdown menu to switch

Comment: Thank you @moonboots